# Icons Does Not Appear in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In my view, I'm calling my icon with below:

```
<td>
 <i id="sthAdd" class="icn_plus"></i>
</td>
```

and the class is:

```
.icn_plus {
  background: url(../images/icons/plus-14x14.png) no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 20px !important;
}
```

It's working in Chrome and IE8 but not in IE7. I've tried seperating url and background repeat, change the url with removing first "/", but it is not working again.

The strange point is at the same time and same view, this is working:

```
<td>
  <input value=" " class="btn_left" />
</td>
```

and class is:

```
.btn_left { 
  background: url(../images/campaign/Ok1.png) no-repeat;    
  width: 20px;  
  height: 30px; 
  border: none; 
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

What am i missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it really necessary for you to support IE7? Think about dropping support for it. Else check your css against it via this page https://caniuse.com Edit: You have to set min browser usage to 0.02%

Comment: I'd try adding display: block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone,

I've solved it with changing the usage:

```
<td>
    <a class="btn" id="sthAdd">
         <img src="../icons/plus-14x14.png" />
    </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<i>` is an inline tag. Try :

```
.icn_plus {
    display: block;
    // or
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../images/icons/plus-14x14.png) no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
}
```